# Express-session new sessions are created every API request

Tags: node.js, angular, cookies, express-session

I'm working with the Spotify API and I'm trying to have the users access token and refresh token saved to their session using express-sessions. I've tried almost everything I could find, and nothing is working.

Here is my app.js code that sets up my express-sessions

```
var app = express();

var corsOptions = {
  origin: 'https://jq-spotify.herokuapp.com',
  credentials: true
}
//Specify that connections from localhost:4200 (the client app) are allowed
app.use(cors(corsOptions));//http://localhost:4200
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
//app.use(cookieParser());

app.use(session({
  name: 'sess-id',
  secret: 'jqSpotifySessionSecretToken',
  saveUninitialized: false,
  resave: false,
  store: new FileStore({}),
  proxy: true,
  cookie: {
    sameSite: true,
    secure: true,
    maxAge: 3600000,
    path: '/'
  }
}));
app.use('/', indexRouter);
```

Here is my index.js file that does the API calling. So first the user has to /login, then he is redirected to /callback where the sessions are saved ( along with access and refresh token ). After that whenever the user makes another API call, express-sessions makes a new session and the access/refresh tokens are no longer saved.

```
router.get('/login', function (req, res, next) {
    var scopes = 'user-read-private user-read-email user-top-read';
    res.redirect('https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize' +
        '?response_type=code' +
        '&show_dialog=true&client_id=' + my_client_id +
        (scopes ? '&scope=' + encodeURIComponent(scopes) : '') +
        '&redirect_uri=' + encodeURIComponent(redirect_uri));
});

router.get('/callback', function (req, res, next) {
    var code = req.query.code || null;
    var error = req.query.error || null;

    if (error) {
        console.error(error);
    } else {
        //we're probably good
        const params = new URLSearchParams();
        params.append('code', code);
        params.append('redirect_uri', redirect_uri);
        params.append('grant_type', 'authorization_code');

        var headers = {
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            'Authorization': 'Basic ' + Buffer.from(my_client_id + ':' + my_client_secret).toString('base64')
        };

        fetch('https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token', {
            method: 'POST',
            body: params,
            headers: headers,
            credentials: 'include',
            withCredentials: true
        }).then(response => {
            if (response.ok) {
                return response.json();
            } else {
                //Could be better to redirect to an error page, but we'll go back to the client.
                res.redirect(client_uri);
            }
        }).then(json => {
            req.session.access_token = json.access_token;
            req.session.refresh_token = json.refresh_token;
            req.session.save();
            res.redirect(client_uri);

        }).catch(err => console.error(err));
    }
});

router.get('*', function (req, res, next) {
    next();

});

router.get('/me', function (req, res, next) {
    makeAPIRequest('https://api.spotify.com/v1/me', res, req);
});


function refresh(req) {
    const params = new URLSearchParams();
    params.append('refresh_token', req.session.refresh_token);
    params.append('grant_type', 'refresh_token');

    var headers = {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'Authorization': 'Basic ' + Buffer.from(my_client_id + ':' + my_client_secret).toString('base64')
    };

    return fetch('https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token', {
        method: 'POST',
        body: params,
        headers: headers,
        credentials: 'include',
        withCredentials: true
    }).then(response => {
        if (response.ok) {
            return response.json();
        } else {
            throw ("Error refreshing token " + req.session.refresh_token + " " + refresh_token + " " + req.session.access_token+" " + access_token);
        }
    }).then(json => {
        req.session.access_token = json.access_token;
        req.session.refresh_token = json.refresh_token;

        req.session.save();
        return Promise.resolve();

    }).catch(err => console.error(err));
}

function makeAPIRequest(url, res, req) {
    var headers = {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' +  req.session.access_token
    };

    fetch(url, {method: 'GET', headers: headers, credentials: 'include', withCredentials: true}).then(response => {
        if (response.ok) {
            return response.json();
        } else {
            if (response.status == 401) {
                refresh(req).then(() => {
                    return fetch(url, {method: 'GET', headers: headers, credentials: 'include', withCredentials: true}).then(response => {
                        if (response.ok) {
                            return response.json();
                        } else {
                            res.status(response.status).end();
                        }
                    });
                });
            } else {
                res.status(response.status).end();
            }
            return null;
        }
    }).then(json => {
        res.json(json);
    }).catch(err => {
        console.error(err);
    });
}
```

Also I'm hosting my server on Heroku !
Again I exhausted everything I could find on the internet and nothing works. I'd appreciate the help, I've been stuck on this for a week ! Thank you !

EDIT: Here is how my client calls the API functions

```
private sendRequestToExpress(endpoint: string): Promise<any> {
        return this.http.get(this.expressBaseUrl + endpoint).toPromise().then((data) => {
            return data;
        });
    }
```

Comment: What kind of client is making the API request?  Is it preserving cookies?  Please show the actual client-side code.  If you're using `fetch()` in browser Javascript, you need the `withCredentials` option.  Cookies are required to preserve access to the session.

Comment: Oof. Sorry about that. This is my first post on Stackoverflow, I'll be sure to be better with my replies. My Client uses a custom spotify.service to call the APIs, using Http Client. The fetch calls are in the index.js under router.get('/callback')

Comment: I'm confused.  Exactly which incoming http request to your server is creating a new express session every time.  And, exactly which line of code is sending that http request to your server?

Answer (score 0):

I would change the return Promise.resolve() so it would execute after the save():

```
}).then(json => {
    req.session.access_token = json.access_token;
    req.session.refresh_token = json.refresh_token;

    req.session.save(function(err) {
        return Promise.resolve();
    });

}).catch(err => console.error(err));
```